# Run all test projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I have one test project for each project in my solution. Is there a way I can run all of them at once or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not dreaming :) This is possible.

> Go to 'Test' menu >> 'Run' >> 'All Tests in Solution'
>
> Keyboard Shortcut : Ctrl + R , A

This will run all the tests in the  solution.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the menu and choose:

```
Test -> Windows -> Test View
```

In that view you just mark them all by pressing `Ctrl + A` and then press the `Run` button